# Pandas: map function along each row of columns defined at runtime (using *args)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to apply a function on the row data of a Pandas DataFrame using *args.
This can be done like this (toy example to retrieve maximum of row):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
def f(*args):
   cols = [c for c in args]
   return max(cols)

m = list(map(f,df['A'],df['B'],df['C'],df['D']))
```

Is there a way to do it in this manner without having to list all the columns separately? For example, when a dataframe has arbitrary columns, defined at runtime.

Finding the maximum could also be done in easier ways but how can one apply arbitrary functions to rows (if *args is not possible)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems you need [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1` for process by rows and each row is converterted to `Series`:

```
def f(x):
   print (x) 
   #sample function
   return x.max()

print (df.apply(f, axis=1))
```

Sample:

```
np.random.seed(45)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(3, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
print (df)
    A   B   C   D
0  75  30   3  32
1  95  61  85  35
2  68  15  65  14

def f(x):
   print (x) 
   #sample function
   return x.max()

A    75
B    30
C     3
D    32
Name: 0, dtype: int32
A    95
B    61
C    85
D    35
Name: 1, dtype: int32
A    68
B    15
C    65
D    14
Name: 2, dtype: int32
```

---

```
print (df.apply(f, axis=1))
0    75
1    95
2    68
dtype: int64
```

And if need list:

```
print (df.apply(f, axis=1).tolist())
[75, 95, 68]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `apply` and `lambda` if you want to send specific columns to the function with axis being specified 1 so it can go row wise i.e

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
def f(*args):
    cols = [c for c in args]
    return max(cols)

m = df.apply(lambda x: f(x['A'],x['B'],x['C'],x['D']),axis=1)
```

Output : print(df.head(5))

```
    A   B   C   D
0  63  95  94  98
1  87  42  18  67
2   1  89  53  42
3  37  62  22  69
4  53   1  41  88
```

```
print(m.head(5))
```

```
0    98
1    87
2    89
3    69
4    88
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

You assemble the columns at run time:

```
cols = [df[x] for x in 'ABCD']
```

and use `*args`:

```
m1 = list(map(f, *cols))
```

Gives the same result:

```
m2 = list(map(f,df['A'],df['B'],df['C'],df['D']))
>>> m1 == m2
True
```